# ENUMs ordinal within JPA entities (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

I've got an entity that is managed within Hibernate's EntityManager. This entity does have a state that is represented by an ENUM. Hibernate does save the ENUM value within the database as integer.

How does Hibernate perform the lookup when the ENUM itself does not specify any numeric values? Does it use the ordinal value (oh dear!)?

Comment: Was asked really often already.

Comment: @jklee [ENUM + hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ENUM+hibernate) does not really answer the question since I wasn't looking for a technical solution, rather the general approach hibernate chooses. However thanks for answering the question ;)

Comment: That's true. Better search is http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ENUM+jpa. Your welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the mapping by specifying you want to use the  name of the enum.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private YourEnum yourEnum;
```

The default is `EnumType.ORDINAL`. It persists the enum in the DB as a number corresponding  to the order of it in the declaration of the enum class.

Whereas the actual behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The magic annotation is `@Enumerated`.

For persist enumerated type  as a string.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

For persist enumerated type as a integer.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
```